# How to write a for loop code in python instead of while

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests

I am quite new to python. Used C, C++, Java & Javascript. All are quite the same in the time of using for loop. It is quite similar to a while loop but in a far better way. I wrote a simple code in while.

```
 newlist = list()
num = int(input("Enter How Many Number You Want To Add: "))

while num > 0:
    inp = input("Enter Number: ")
    value  = int(inp)
    newlist.append(value)
    num = num -1
print('Your Sum Is',sum(newlist))
```

How I can change the while loop to for loop in this python code.

Comment: `for i in range(num):` and remove `num = num-1`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. As I mentioned I am new to python. So I can not find any reason for your downvote.Sir thank you so much anyways.

Comment: This is stuff that you should find in Python tutorial, not on SO. There are also many questions detailing how to convert one loop into another. - Hence the downvote. Also, not a "sir".

Answer (score 0):

For vs while ... what you want is to use range():

```
for i in range(num):
    newlist.append(int(raw_input('Enter Number')))
s = sum(newlist)
```

or a list comprehension all in one line

```
s = sum([int(raw_input('Enter Number')) for i in range(num)])
```

Should work

Comment: Thank you, sir. I got that.

Comment: Note that `raw_input()` is for python 2. Use `input()` in python 3.